# Docker container unreachable from remote machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, connection-refused

I use `docker` and `docker-compose` to deploy and run my java application running on port 5555.

I run it as  `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

But if I run telnet command outside of my server where docker container is runnig I  get `Connection refused` message. If run it inside the server everything is fine.

So these things are checked:

**$: docker-compose ps**

[image]

**$: ufw status**

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
5555/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5555/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  auth:
    container_name: auth
    image: registryimg
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
ADD target/auth.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 5555
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

**Update 1**

From the docker logs of my container I found that application binds correctly to desired port:

```
2019-01-18 10:18:11.481 DEBUG 1 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-1] io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  : [id: 0xaf27337e] REGISTERED
2019-01-18 10:18:11.485 DEBUG 1 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-1] io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  : [id: 0xaf27337e] BIND: localhost/127.0.0.1:5555
2019-01-18 10:18:11.489 DEBUG 1 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-1] io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  : [id: 0xaf27337e, L:/127.0.0.1:5555] ACTIVE
```

**Update 2**

From my home computer I run telnet command `telnet myhost 5555` and I get an error:

```
Trying myhost...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

After it's done I watch my container logs and they are empty (netty didn't register any connections).

Else I want to point that if I telnet another container with potgresql inside it - everything is ok.

Comment: Did you create the server with docker-machine? Does your server have a firewall? Does it let in traffic at :5555?

Comment: do you authenticate with the right credentials?

Comment: @maxm I create it using gitlab ci. Yes I have a firewall, and I already attached its info showing tcp port 5555 is opened.

Comment: @UlrichZendler I do not need to authenticate, port has to be opened for all incoming requests

Comment: @nllsdfc but if you are trying to access a database or something inside that container, then you might get a connection denied error for that database. Are you sure the error is happening in the line where you connect to the container?

Comment: @UlrichZendler nah containers see each other. The problem is that I can't reach my application running inside docker container running on remote server from my home computer. I keep googling and I guess that I have to reconfigure my application port it uses inside the container.

Comment: @And moreover I can reach another container remotely (I mean postgres container), but not my java app inside another container

Comment: That is what I meant, I feel like it isn't a problem with the container, but with your application not listening/fetching from that port

Comment: @UlrichZendler I attached logs from my running application where we can see it was bound correctly to the port

Comment: can you also share the error message that you are getting? best would be if you log into the container you are running and give us the stackstrace error message.

Comment: @UlrichZendler Updated question. And also there are no messages at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, shot answer is think **what host you are binding**.

In my case netty server was bound like this:

```
BIND: localhost/127.0.0.1:5555
```

I've change it to:

```
BIND: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5555
```

And it works like a charm!